# Other than header file what do you need to use the functions defined in header

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

I have a myheader.h file, i have included it successfully in my VC++ project, but i am not able to use any of it functions. It gives the error Unresolved external symbol (my function definition). What am i missing?

```
//Here is my code snippet
#include "myHeaders/myheader.h"
void main (){
    head_gen();
}
```

It doesnt build and the error is

```
Unresolved external symbol void__head_gen()
```

etc.  Has it something to do with .lib file or something else?

Comment: so you are able to build but not run the project is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the implementation of the function `head_gen()`. This can be in

- a source file,
- an object file or
- a library

You should have one of them gotten with the header file.

If you have a .cpp file, add it to your project.

If you have a .obj or .lib file, add it as dependecy in the Project Properties:

```
Configuration Properties / Linker / Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

If the .obj or .lib file is in a different directory than your project, don't forget to add the path:

```
Configuration Properties / Linker / General -> Additional Library Directories
```

Answer (score 1):

I develop mostly on Linux and use vi as an editor. But when I see such errors, it usually is one of the following reasons:

1. The function `head_gen()` is defined under a `namespace` and the source code where `head_gen()` is used does not have the `using namespace` statement.
2. Has `head_gen()` been defined in `myHeader.cpp`? That could be another reason why the function is not "visible".

HTH,
Sriram